# Querying different EntitySubclasses in one query

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have 3 entities that have something in common.

```
@Entity
public class BaseEntity {
    Date updatedAt;
}

@EntitySubclass
public class A extends BaseEntity {
    String someData;
}

@EntitySubclass
public class B extends BaseEntity {
    int someData;
}

@EntitySubclass
public class C extends BaseEntity {
    boolean someData;
}
```

Can I make one query to create `List<BaseEntity>` or `Query<BaseEntity>`?

Supposedly something like this?

```
ofy().load().type(User.class).filter("updatedAt > ", someDate)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, with Objectify I think you can. Here they give an example:

https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Entities#Polymorphism

I think the datastore can't do it natively, but Objectify will setup a structure for you that allows polymorphism anyway.

Comment: I've maneged to make it working. It's exactly as I thought in the question. However, forget about looking throught your entities on Google cloud console as all the entities will be under BaseEntity and the table joins all the fields... it's not as readable anymore

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is not strictly correct. With [Objectify](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Queries#Polymoprhism), you can query by kind on a superclass and it will seamlessly query all applicable datastore entities which match the inheriting @Entity annotated classes.

Comment: Yes, I was about to post the same.  Whilst it is not possible with the low-level Datastore API, Objectify provides support for this kind of inheritance (by storing metadata in `^i` and `^d` properties). We've been using exactly this kind of query for some time.